# Problem creating an org-mode link to a pdf file from PDFView

Tags: org-mode, org-link, pdf-tools

When I try to store a link to a pdf file (opened with PDFView), I get the following error

```
Unable to percent escape character: \342
```

The link is stored with the following url:

```
Stored: file:/tmp/mozilla_chriad0/file.pdf::%PDF-1.6 %\324\343\317\323
```

When looking for a solution, I found the `url-util` package. I came up with the following:

```
(setq x "file:/tmp/mozilla_chriad0/file.pdf::%PDF-1.6 %\324\343\317\323")

(require 'url-util)

(setq y (url-encode-url x))
```

When I create a link with the content of `y`, which is `[[file:/tmp/mozilla_chriad0/file.pdf::%PDF-1.6%20%%D4%E3%CF%D3]]`, the link works as intended.

My question: How can I hook into this process and convert the link to the right encoding so that the above error does not occur?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that `pdf-tools` is installed and working. What you are asking for also requires the package `org-pdfview` which is available from melpa. In this package functions like`org-pdfview-store-link` are declared.